# Available Miicrosoft Cognitive regions

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm looking for a Voice Authentication API, and I find Microsoft's one.
When looking at prices, it asks you for a region. The problem is that 
[it only shows a region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3sYY.png)

I've been reading about Azure's regions, and it say that is where data is stored, so my question is if it would be possible to use it in a different region than allowed.
Thanks (and sorry for my spelling mistakes).

Answer (score 0):

## *Quick Answer:*

Normally yes, **but currently the Speaker Recognition API is only offered out of the WestUS datacenter.**

**If it's mandatory that you have low-latency when using the service, I suggest you look into setting up and/or temporarily subscribing to a CDN service.** Or, if you have a lot of time on your hands, and know waaaaay more than I do about this subject, you may be able to design a local cache to mitigate latency if you're distant from WestUS.

## *Less-Quick Answer:*

First off, you should use the dashboard interface at https://portal.azure.com to sign up. You will first need to create a Pay-As-You-Go subscription as your payment-medium, but it will give you much more control over & visibility into your service.

Here's what the signup pane looks like inside of https://portal.azure.com:
[image]

It appears that, in it's current "PREVIEW" deployment, you are right the services is **only offered from the the WestUS data center.** Normally you will have the option to one of ten's of global datacenters, but it is common that PREVIEW services aren't deployed globally until they're out of PREVIEW status.

If the problem you are looking to remediate is **latency-based,** look into the CDN suggestion in my "Quick Answer."

If your issue is about getting **different pricing based on your location**, the location of the datacenter you choose will not affect this. If geographic-discounting applies to you, **it is based on the country that is assigned to your Microsoft Username/Password combination at the time it was created.** This value cannot be changed once a username/password combo has been created, and consequently, any payment info used along with this uname/pass will need to have a billing address in the same country.